# Multiplication of two numbers by dividing them into a third of their size

Tags: matrices, algorithms, contest-math

A little Background: If we have two numbers (ab) and (cd) where a,b,c,d are digits of these numbers. Then we can multiply them by doing this:

```
(a × 10^1 + b × 10^0) × (c × 10^1 + d × 10^0) =  ca × 10^2 + (ad + bc) × 10^1 + bd × 10^0.
```

It requires four multiplications ca, ad, bc, bd. But we can accomplish this product by computing just three multiplications by noticing that:

```
ad + bc = (a + b)(c + d) − ac − bd
```

Now if we do the same thing with numbers (abc), (def) then the minimum multiplications that are required are 5.
But I have been able to find the product by using 6 multiplications and not 5. How can we do that?

Here is my work till now:

```
We calculate the following multiplications:

    M0 = (a + c ) * (d + f )
    M1 = ad
    M2 = cf
    M3 = be
    M4 = (a+b)*(d+e)
    M5 = (b+c)*(e+f)
    Thus the answer to the matrix multiplication problem is:
    M1 x 10^4 + M2 + ( M4 – M1 – M3 ) x 10^3 + ( M5 – M3 – M2 ) x 10^1 + ( M0 + M3 – M2 – M1) x 10^2
```